# Is there a way to COUNT data without adding a column to the resulting query, while still filtering by it?

Tags: sql, subquery

Because I received help from an earlier post, I was able to get a code that does correctly:

```
select *
from (
    select e.employeename, s.skilldescription,
        count(*) over(partition by e.employeeid) as count
    from employeeskills_t k
    inner join employee_t e on k.employeeid = e.employeeid
    inner join skill_t s on k.skillid=s.skillid 
) t
where count> 1
order by employeename, skilldescription
```

But it generates an extra column, `count`, which I don't need.

I don't understand SQL that well, so I dont know if a command exists.

Comment: You are probably looking for `group by` and `having`, also, please add your DBMS tag, such as sql-server, mysql, etc.

Comment: No, you can't. The options you have are: 1) Ignore the extra column while receiving the data. 2) Naming the specific columns you want in the first line: that is, instead of `select *` you'll need to replace that `*` by the comma-separated list of column names you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `select *` gives you all columns available in the `from` clause.

Here, the `from` clause it itself a subquery, which returns 3 columns ; the third column is the count, which is needed in the outer query for filtering (that's the "last" `where` clause).

Since we cannot *not* return that column from the subquery, we can instead ignore it in the output. This means we need to enumerate the columns we want, rather than blindly use `*`.

Columns in the outer query have the same names as those returned by the subuqery. Here there are only two columns that are needed, so that's quite short to write :

Just change that `select * from (...) t where ...`

... To : `select employeename, skilldescription from (...) t where ...`

Side note: some databases support a specific syntax to select all columns *but* a few named columns. BigQuery has [`SELECT * EXCEPT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_except) - but that's not a widely available feature in other RDBMS, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! This helped with what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

- since you have used windows function you will see the results of each row and so the column will remain there
- you have two option either use the `group by` , where you can just filter on the count values using `having` clause or you could use the windows function and then select only the relevant columns you need that would be:

```
with main as (
        select e.employeename, s.skilldescription,
            count(*) over(partition by e.employeeid) as count
        from employeeskills_t k
        inner join employee_t e on k.employeeid = e.employeeid
        inner join skill_t s on k.skillid=s.skillid 
       ) 
    select 
    e.employeename, 
    s.skilldescription,
    where count> 1
    order by employeename, skilldescription
```

version 2 :

```
   select e.employeename
        from employeeskills_t k
        inner join employee_t e on k.employeeid = e.employeeid
        inner join skill_t s on k.skillid=s.skillid 
group by 1
having count(e.employeenam) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for distinct values of employeename, skilldescription with count of emp ids more than one, same can be achieved using group by & having.
Please check if the below helps.

```
select e.employeename, s.skilldescription 
from employeeskills_t k
inner join employee_t e on k.employeeid = e.employeeid
inner join skill_t s on k.skillid=s.skillid 
group by e.employeename, s.skilldescription
having COUNT(e.employeeid) > 1
order by employeename, skilldescription;
```